# How to add button to a messenger welcome screen?

Tags: node.js, curl, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-chatbot

I have simple bot ,I want to set a greating text and add three buttons to it

something like this.

Welcom Johhn to man utd'

-first button

-second button

-third button

here is what I have tried

```
    $ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
    "greeting": [
      {
        "locale":"default",
        "text":"Hello {{user_first_name}}! Welcome to Man utd"
    message: {
          "attachment": {
          "type": "template",
          "payload": {
              "template_type": "generic",
              "elements": [{
                  "title": "Hi , thanks for messaging videommerce",
                  "buttons": [{
                      "type": "postback",
                      "title": "Select video purpose",
                      "payload": "purpose"
                  }, {
                      "type": "postback",
                      "title": "How to create video",
                      "payload": "create"
                  },{
                    "type": "web_url",
                    "url": "https://www.videommerce.com/",
                    "title": "Talk to us directly (moving to Customerly live chat)"
                  }],
              }]
          }
      }
        }
      }
   ]
  }' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=token"
```

What do I need to change to get what I want?

Answer (score 0):

The greeting webhook does not have the attachment property, as you can see here: [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/greeting/).

So, your greeting will work only with the parameters locale and text:

```
$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
    "greeting": [
      {
        "locale":"default",
        "text":"Hello {{user_first_name}}! Welcome to Man utd"
      }]}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=token"
```

If you want to show some buttons to the user, the correct way is to call another webhook, after you send the greeting one, the persistent-menu, as described [here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/persistent-menu). This code will do the work:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "setting_type" : "call_to_actions",
  "thread_state" : "existing_thread",
  "call_to_actions":[
    {
      "type":"postback",
      "title":"Help",
      "payload":"DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD_FOR_HELP"
    },
    {
      "type":"postback",
      "title":"Latest Posts",
      "payload":"DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD_FOR_LATEST_POSTS"
    },
    {
      "type":"web_url",
      "title":"View Website",
      "url":"http://yoursite.com/"
    }
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

Comment: hi aldo I get the following error : `{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) The parameter setting_type is required",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "DAoKxIRYVvg"
    }
}`

Comment: hi @user9964622, I have just edited, try now with setting_type.

Comment: unfortunatelly this add adds a persitent menu not the buttons I wanted

Comment: @user9964622, as far as I know, facebook does not have static buttons the user always sees when he starts the conversation. I imagine what you are trying to accomplish and I made something similar before, however, I made that using the postback buttons (and, it seems you tried to use them inside the greetings). If you see this [link] (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/buttons/postback/) you are gonna see that the first parameter is the user id, so, this postback is an answer after a conversation starts.